# Comparison xsl output

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file like

```
<section>
<dlentry xtrf="books.xml">
<dd>
<msgph>Harry Potter
</msgph>
</dd>
</dlentry>

<dlentry xtrf="books.xml">
<dd>
<msgph>1984
</msgph>
</dd>
</dlentry>

<dlentry xtrf="books.xml">
<dd>
<msgph>The Great Gatsby
</msgph>
</dt>
</dlentry>

<dlentry>
<dd>
<dl>
<dlentry xtrf="myFavouriteBooks.xml">
<dd>
<parml>
<plentry>
<pd>
<msgph>Harry Potter
</msgph>
</pd>    
</plentry>
</parml>
</dd>
</dlentry>
</dl>
</dd>        
</dlentry>

<dlentry xtrf="myBooks.xml">
<dd>
<msgph>1984
</msgph>
</dd>
</dlentry>

</section>
```

And what I need to do is using XSL create 2 lists, first - with values of "**dlentry**" element that has an **id!="books.xml"** and second - with **id="books.xml"**. And after I should compare theese lists and give the attention message with all not matched elements.

Something like *"Attention! !MISSING! **1984**  !MISSING! **The Great Gatsby**"*

Now I have xsl:

```
<xsl:variable name="inBooks" select="/dlentry/dd/msgph"/>    
<xsl:variable name="notInBooks" select="//dlentry[not(contains(@xtrf,'books.xml))]//msgph/node()[not(self::dlentry)])" as="item()*"/>

<title>Books</title>

<refbody>  
   <section>
      <dl>                              
         <dlentry>                   
         <xsl:variable name="notMatched" select="//dlentry[not(contains(@xtrf,'books.xml'))]//msgph[msgph !='$inBooks']/node()[not(self::dlentry)])"/>

            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$notMatched">
                  <xsl:for-each select="section/dl/dlentry">
                     <dt>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('!MISSING! ', msgph")/>
                     </dt>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:for-each select="section/dl/dlentry">
                    <dt>
                       <xsl:value-of select="msgph"/>
                    </dt>
                </xsl:for-each>

               </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose> 

        <dt>                               
           <xsl:value-of select="$notInBooks"/> 
        </dt>
<../>
```

And it gives the output:

```
<title>Books</title>

<refbody>
  <section>
     <dl>
        <dlentry>

           <dt>The Great Gatsby</dt>
           <dt>1984</dt>
           <dt>Harry Potter Part 2</dt>
           <dt>Harry Potter Part 1</dt>
           <dd/>
           <dt>Harry Potter Part 1 Harry Potter Part 2</dt>
        </..>
```

I have tried hundreds of combinations, but it doesnt work.. Now it supposed to add "!MISSING!" to a list "id=books", but it gives just an empty element
Can you point me, where is my mistake, please?

Comment: Can you post a minimal but well-formed XML input sample? I am afraid it is hard to understand what you want to compare if the markup like `<msgph>Harry Potter Part 1
<msgph>` is not well-formed.  I also guess you want to use `msgph !=$inBooks`.

Comment: I have changed the xsl, now it contains the minimum info to explain what I am dealing with

Comment: And thank you for the feedback! I But I dont understand how I can use 'msgph !=$inBooks'.. I am not experienced with xsl, but it seems not possible.. as 'msgph' not in the same location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can at least use XSLT 2.0, then you can use

```
<xsl:variable name="b1" select="//dlentry[contains(@xtrf, 'books.xml')]"/>
<xsl:variable name="b2" select="//dlentry[not(contains(@xtrf, 'books.xml'))]"/>

<xsl:variable name="b3" select="$b1[not(.//msgph/normalize-space() = $b2//msgph/normalize-space())]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! So compact and elegant! And it works perfectly :)